# analysis of The Man Who Sold the World

Tags: key, analysis, tonal

So because I looked at the sheet music I assume the home key is either F or D minor. I understand the basics of using Roman numerals I'm just not sure if D minor should be i or F should be I.
It seems like the tonal center is changing to C in the chorus.

Also I found it interesting that the dramatic chord in the chorus is said to be a B flat minor in the David Bowie version and a D flat major in the Nirvana version.

Comment: I remember watching an Adam Neely video where he quoted a book about harmonic analysis of modern pop /country / rock songs, where the idea is that there's no definitive key, there's some ambiguity (and / or constant modulation) between the relative minor and relative major. I don't remember which video was it, or the book's author, maybe someone else can chime in? Edit: It's this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DVPq_-oJV5U